# How to get the "Lambda" symbol in Cmder Powershell with posh-git AFTER the git info?

Tags: powershell, cmder, posh-git

I installed cmder and I use it with Powershell and posh-git. posh-git puts the git info after the Lambda, and the cursor after the git info, without any spaces:
[image: my prompt]

How do I change this to have the Lambda appear AFTER the git info? I already played witrh `$PrePrompt` and `$PostPrompt` in `config\user_profile.ps1` but this only affects anything before the git info.

Answer (score 0):

Use the global `$GitPromptSettings` variable to set the prompt suffix in `posh-git`:

```
$GitPromptSettings.DefaultPromptSuffix = 'λ'
```

Comment: I added this to `user_profile.ps1` but all I get is: `The property 'DefaultPromptSuffix' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.` Or do I have to set this elsewhere?

Comment: @rabejens Make sure you do it _after_ `Import-Module posh-git`

Comment: That's exactly what I did.